# How to fix on dspace 6.3 --> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException

Tags: solaris, dspace, solar

[org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brFqY.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say, with so little information, but my guess would be that you've configured DSpace to contact Solr (solr.server) on an address other than the loopback interface (127.0.0.1 or ::1) but have not disabled the filter in Solr that only accepts requests from the loopback interface (LocalHostRestrictionFilter.localhost).